# How to index coordinate data according to a grid in R?

Tags: r, indexing, grid, coordinates, partitioning

I have coordinate data (x-coordinates and y-coordinates) on a scale between:
Xpos: 27-1367nm, Ypos: 67-1014nm. A data set consists of about 2500-3500 data points.
Here is the header of such a data set:

```
   XPos YPos
1    29  211
2    31  609
3    33 1001
4    35  508
5    37  424
6    39  584
7    40  378
8    41  204
9    41  444
10   41  872 
...
```

[![Data plotted][1]][1]

Now I would like to index the data points by applying a grid consisting of equal sized quadrants onto the data in R. The result should be a new column "grid_index" containing a unique quadrant_ID in which the data points are located (see image). Is there an easy way to do this? I would like to try different grid unit sizes to partition the data e.g. quadrants sized 50nm, 100nm, 200nm or 400nm and rectangles sized 100nm x 200nm or 50nm x100nm.

[![Grid for data pint indexing][2]][2]

[![Each grid quadrant should have an unique ID][3]][3]

I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach with `findInterval`:

First set up a matrix that has the appropriate number of indices:

```
pos.matrix <- matrix(1:35,byrow = TRUE, nrow = 5)
pos.matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
[2,]    8    9   10   11   12   13   14
[3,]   15   16   17   18   19   20   21
[4,]   22   23   24   25   26   27   28
[5,]   29   30   31   32   33   34   35
```

Next use `findInterval` to find the indices of the matrix of where it lies. You can control the size of the grid using the `by =` argument. Note that the dimensions of the matrix must match the number of intervals provided in `findInterval`. We need to use `abs` because the y values are decreasing on the graph.

```
grid <- apply(cbind(findInterval(data[,"XPos"],seq(0,1400,by = 200)),
                    abs(findInterval(data[,"YPos"],seq(0,1000,by = 200)) - 6)),
              MARGIN = 1,
              function(x) pos.matrix[x[2],x[1]])
grid[1:25]
[1] 30 34 31 17 19 26 15 31 19  5 18 32 25 25 14 20 22 19 35  2 16  8 29 29 16
plot(NA,xlim = c(0,1400), ylim = c(0,1000), xlab = "XPos", ylab = "YPos", cex.axis = 0.8)
text(data[,1],data[,2], labels = grid, cex = 0.4)
```

[image]

**Sample Data**

```
set.seed(3)
data <- data.frame(XPos = runif(1000,0,1400), YPos = runif(1000,0,1000))
```

[image]

Comment: the issue is that his data isn't in a matrix format natively. So he needs to convert his data into a matrix, which would introduce 0's into it,  which might invalidate your answer unless you can find a way to adjust the solution to work on a 2 column dataframe.

Comment: It currently works on a 2 column `data.frame`. Please see the **Sample Data** section.

Comment: Hi Ian! Thank you very much. I tried it with my data and it works perfectly. I am relatively new to R and coding and I am trying to understand the solution you provided. Could you possibly explain what the argument "MARGIN = 1" does? Thank you!

Comment: `apply` applies a function along the margins of a matrix, array or data.frame. Because `cbind` makes a 2 column matrix, we want to apply our function to every row of that matrix. The `1` margin is for every row, and the `2` margin is every column. You could actually subset `pos.matrix` directly, but I thought this would be easier to understand.